# When value emit in collection of Firebase the snapshot query is run multiple times but I want to run once

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I currently have a bug within my project where my Firebase queries are being executed multiple times.

Here is an example piece of code that used to execute just once but now executes multiple times

```
await this.afs.collection('/layouts', ref => ref.where('store_uid', '==', this.current_store_uid)).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
            console.log("layout 111")
            data.forEach((docs:any)=>{
                const startDate = docs.payload.doc.data().start_date.toDate()
                const endDate = docs.payload.doc.data().end_date.toDate()
                if(startDate <= current_date &&  endDate > current_date){
                    this.current_layout_data = [docs.payload.doc.data()]
                }
            })
            this.layoutData()
        });
```

I want to execute the code once not multiple times after changes are made.

I use snapshotChanges() because I need to execute this code whenever layout collection change from this file or another file also.

while executing the below code to update the layout collection and
I used snapshotChanges() so the above code executes one time, but in my project, the above code executes two times.

```
async save_data(data) {
    await this.afs.doc('/layouts/' + this.current_template_id).update({
        layout_json_saved: data.layout_json_temp
    })
}
```

I tried .get().pipe() but I'm not getting the data from the below code.

```
console.log("Flow coming here")
    await this.afs.collection('/layouts', ref => ref.where('store_uid', '==', this.current_store_uid)).get().pipe(map(data => {
        console.log("It's not coming here:-", data)
        this.layoutData()
    }));
```

Here is layoutData function code.

```
layoutData(){
    if (this.current_layout_data?.length > 0) {
        if(this.current_layout_data[0]){
            localStorage.setItem('Current_layout_EndDate',this.current_layout_data[0].end_date.toDate())
        }

        this.show_add_product = false;

        if(this.is_preview_clicked){
            this.current_layout_data = [JSON.parse(this.preview_obj)]
        }

        this.preview_url = `https://digital-circular-pro-front.web.app/${this.store_data[0].company_name_slug}/${this.store_data[0].branch_name_slug}/${this.current_layout_data[0].uid}?preview=true`
        this.layout_type = this.current_layout_data[0].layout_type
        if (this.do_not_refresh_iframe != true) {
            this.iframe_src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/dc.html?store_uid=' + this.current_store_uid + '&template_id=' + this.current_layout_data[0]?.uid + '&r=11');
        }

        this.show_add_product = false

        this.current_template_id = this.current_layout_data[0]?.uid;
        this.componentService.currentTemplateId(this.current_template_id)

        this.current_select_product_id = this.current_layout_data[0]?.selected_product_id;
        if(this.current_select_product_id !== '' && this.current_select_product_id !== undefined){
            this.show_edit_form = true;
        }
        this.current_select_product_index = this.current_layout_data[0]?.layout_json_temp.findIndex(obj => obj.id == this.current_select_product_id);
        this.current_select_product_data = this.current_layout_data[0]?.layout_json_temp.find(obj => obj.id == this.current_select_product_id);
        if (this.current_select_product_id !== '' && this.current_select_product_id !== undefined) {
            this.isVideo = this.current_select_product_data?.isVideo
            this.afs.collection('/store-items', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', this.current_select_product_id)).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
                this.current_selected_product_data_full = data.map((e: any) => {
                    return {
                        upc_code: e.payload.doc.data().upc_code ? e.payload.doc.data().upc_code : '',
                        product_description: e.payload.doc.data().product_description ? e.payload.doc.data().product_description : '',
                        pack: e.payload.doc.data().pack ? e.payload.doc.data().pack : '',
                        price_label_format: this.getFormate(this.current_select_product_data?.content),
                        price_format_value1: this.getPrice(this.current_select_product_data?.content, 'lable1')?this.getPrice(this.current_select_product_data?.content , 'lable1'):'',
                        price_format_value2: this.getPrice(this.current_select_product_data?.content , 'lable2')?this.getPrice(this.current_select_product_data?.content, 'lable2'):'',
                        price_format_value3: this.getPrice(this.current_select_product_data?.content, 'lable3')?this.getPrice(this.current_select_product_data?.content, 'lable3'):'',
                        price_label_svg: this.getSVG(this.current_select_product_data?.content),
                        price_label_highlight: e.payload.doc.data().price_label_highlight ? e.payload.doc.data().price_label_highlight : '',
                        product_url: e.payload.doc.data().product_url ? e.payload.doc.data().product_url : '',
                        new_window: e.payload.doc.data().new_window ? e.payload.doc.data().new_window : '',
                        autoplay: e.payload.doc.data().autoplay ? e.payload.doc.data().autoplay : false,
                        hide_price_label: e.payload.doc.data().hide_price_label ? e.payload.doc.data().hide_price_label : '',
                        hide_addtolist_label: e.payload.doc.data().hide_addtolist_label ? e.payload.doc.data().hide_addtolist_label : '',
                        hide_productname_label: e.payload.doc.data().hide_productname_label ? e.payload.doc.data().hide_productname_label : '',
                        cost: e.payload.doc.data().cost ? e.payload.doc.data().cost : '',
                        srp: e.payload.doc.data().srp ? e.payload.doc.data().srp : '',
                        category: e.payload.doc.data().category ? e.payload.doc.data().category : '',
                        uid: e.payload.doc.id,
                        product_image: this.getImage(this.current_select_product_data?.content, e.payload.doc.id) ? this.getImage(this.current_select_product_data?.content, e.payload.doc.id) : 'https://via.placeholder.com/30/cecece/cecece',
                        is_saved: e.payload.doc.data().is_saved ? e.payload.doc.data().is_saved : false,
                        isVideo: this.current_select_product_data?.isVideo ? this.current_select_product_data?.isVideo : false,
                        // created_at          : e.payload.doc.data()['created_at'],
                    };
                });
                this.imageurl1x = this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.product_image ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.product_image : '';
                this.current_price_label_format = this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_label_format;
                this.price_label_svg = this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_label_svg;
                this.price_format_value1 = this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value1 ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value1 : '';
                this.price_format_value2 = this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value2 ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value2 : '';
                this.price_format_value3 = this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value3 ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value3 : '';
                this.product_update_form.patchValue({
                    uid: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.uid,
                    product_image: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.product_image,
                    upc_code: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.upc_code,
                    product_description: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.product_description,
                    pack: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.pack,
                    price_label_format: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_label_format,
                    category: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.category,
                    product_url: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.product_url,
                    new_window: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.new_window? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.new_window : false,
                    autoplay: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.autoplay? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.autoplay : false,
                    hide_price_label: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.hide_price_label ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.hide_price_label : false,
                    hide_addtolist_label: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.hide_addtolist_label ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.hide_addtolist_label : false,
                    hide_productname_label: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.hide_productname_label ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.hide_productname_label : false,
                    price_format_value1: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value1 ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value1 : '',
                    price_format_value2: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value2 ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value2 : '',
                    price_format_value3: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value3 ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_format_value3 : '',
                    price_label_svg: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_label_svg ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.price_label_svg : '',
                    isVideo: this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.isVideo ? this.current_selected_product_data_full[0]?.isVideo : '',
                });
            });
        }
        this.do_not_refresh_iframe = true;

        this.last_publish_timestamp = this.current_layout_data[0]?.last_publish_timestamp;
        this.last_save_timestamp = this.current_layout_data[0]?.last_save_timestamp;

            const start_date = new Date(this.current_layout_data[0]?.start_date.seconds * 1000).getFullYear()
                + '-' + ('0' + (new Date(this.current_layout_data[0]?.start_date.seconds * 1000).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
                + '-' + ('0' + (new Date(this.current_layout_data[0]?.start_date.seconds * 1000).getDate())).slice(-2);

            const end_date = new Date(this.current_layout_data[0]?.end_date.seconds * 1000).getFullYear()
                + '-' + ('0' + (new Date(this.current_layout_data[0]?.end_date.seconds * 1000).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
                + '-' + ('0' + (new Date(this.current_layout_data[0]?.end_date.seconds * 1000).getDate())).slice(-2);

        this.page_type1 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page1_type;
        this.page_type2 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page2_type;
        this.page_type3 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page3_type;
        this.page_type4 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page4_type;
        this.page_type5 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page5_type;
        this.imageurl1 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page1_url;
        this.imageurl2 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page2_url;
        this.imageurl3 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page3_url;
        this.imageurl4 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page4_url;
        this.imageurl5 = this.current_layout_data[0]?.page5_url;


            this.layout_form.patchValue({
                layout_type: this.layout_type ? this.layout_type : this.current_layout_data[0]?.layout_type,
                page1_type: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page1_type,
                page2_type: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page2_type,
                page3_type: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page3_type,
                page4_type: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page4_type,
                page5_type: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page5_type,
                page1_url: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page1_url,
                page2_url: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page2_url,
                page3_url: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page3_url,
                page4_url: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page4_url,
                page5_url: this.current_layout_data[0]?.page5_url,
                terms: this.current_layout_data[0]?.terms,
                include_header_checkbox: this.current_layout_data[0]?.include_header_checkbox,
                start_date: start_date,
                end_date: end_date,
                header_text: this.current_layout_data[0]?.header_text,
                uid: this.current_layout_data[0]?.uid,
                layout_json_temp: this.current_layout_data[0]?.layout_json_temp,
                layout_json: this.current_layout_data[0]?.layout_json,
                layout_json_saved: this.current_layout_data[0]?.layout_json_saved || []
            });
        } else {
        let start_date = new Date();
        start_date = new Date(start_date.getTime() - 86400000)
        const end_date = new Date(start_date.getTime() + (86400000*15));
        const include_header_checkbox = 0;

        const layout_store_data =
        {
            store_uid: this.current_store_uid,
            start_date,
            end_date,
            header_text: '',
            include_header_checkbox,
            is_publish: 0,
            layout_json: [],
            layout_type: this.layout_type ? this.layout_type : 'grid',
            page1_type: '',
            page2_type: '',
            page3_type: '',
            page4_type: '',
            page5_type: '',
            page1_url: '',
            page2_url: '',
            page3_url: '',
            page4_url: '',
            page5_url: '',
            layout_json_temp: [],
            layout_json_saved: [],
            terms: '',
            last_save_timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
            last_publish_timestamp: new Date('2001-01-01'),
            updated_at: new Date()
        };

        const layout_data_new = this.afs.collection('/layouts').add(layout_store_data).then(docRef => {
            const itemRefx2 = this.afs.doc('/layouts/' + docRef.id);
            itemRefx2.update({ uid: docRef.id });
            this.current_template_id = docRef.id;
            this.layout_form.patchValue({
                uid: docRef.id,
            });
            this.iframe_src = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/dc.html?store_uid=' + this.current_store_uid + '&template_id=' + this.current_template_id + '&r=11');

        });

    }
    this.product_update_form.reset()
    this.product_add_form.reset({
        hide_price_label: false,
        hide_addtolist_label: false,
        hide_productname_label: false,
    })
    const temp_form_data = this.layout_form.value
    console.log("layout data temp_form_data", temp_form_data);        
}
```

I created one form and if that form value change then I want to execute some code. So I put below code in ngOnInit().

```
this.layout_form.valueChanges.subscribe(selectedValue => {
        this.layout_type = selectedValue.layout_type
        this.preview_obj = JSON.stringify(selectedValue)
        
        if(this.is_changes){
            if(JSON.stringify(selectedValue.layout_json_temp) == JSON.stringify(selectedValue.layout_json_saved)){
                console.log("if")
                this.show_discard = false
                this.publish_btn_class = 'disable-class'
                this.is_save_active = false
                let publish_btn:any = document.getElementsByClassName('publish-btn')[0]
            }else{
                console.log("else")
                this.show_discard = true
                this.is_save_active = true
                this.publish_btn_class = 'active-class'
            }
        }else{
            console.log("else else")
            this.show_discard = false
            this.publish_btn_class = 'disable-class'
            this.is_save_active = false
            this.is_changes = true
        }
      })
```

My angular is "^10.1.6".

Hope you understand the question!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035365/how-can-i-query-firestore-db-only-once-i-want-to-avoid-that-when-something-chan?

Comment: If I understand the purpose of this function call, you're trying to _constantly_ get the `startDate` and `endDate` of the collection documents that match your query. Based on your complaint, you're trying to do this just once, but since you're using `.snapshotChanges().subscribe`, the callback will be used however times the data changes, you might need to use `.get().pipe()` instead...

Comment: @AlanMaldonado As per your suggestion, I tried pipe() but I am not getting data. Check this screenshot of code: https://pasteboard.co/kQQvxaVBSQJG.png   Also for your information, I needed to use both snapshot() and pipe() in my application because data is keep changing from other file also.